# When using UISearchDisplayController the popover does not show on an iPad view controller

Tags: ios, ipad

I created a UISearchDisplayController inside a UIViewController, which lives inside a UINavigationController.

I used the normal init:

```
self.displayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
self.displayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.displayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.displayController.delegate = self;
self.displayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
```

This code works fine and shows the dimmed view in iPhone but on iPad it does nothing. I was looking online and most people are saying that it should automatically display a popover with the results. I don't see this happening at all. Do I have to do this a different way for iPad UIViewControllers?

I am creating this all programmatically.

Answer (score 6):

I noticed the same issue when using a UISearchDisplayController in a modal view controller (PageSheet style) on iPad and iOS7: the UISearchDisplayController doesn't attach itself to the view hierarchy of your view controller as it does on iPhone.

As a unclean but working workaround, you can attach yourself the tableView generated by the UISearchDisplayController to your view hierarchy in one of the delegate method:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        tableView.frame = self.view.frame;
        [self.view addSubview:tableView];
    }
}
```

There are 2 caveats:

1. You have to create and display the dimmed view yourself, just create a view with black background color and 50% alpha on top of self.view with the same frame size
2. You may have to fix the content insets of the table view provided by the UISearchDisplayController.

For example:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f); 
}
```